# best place to configure a global setting for a gem Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api-client

I am using the [Google Api Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) gem in a rails application.

I need to set the following configuration globally:

```
Google::Apis::RequestOptions.default.retries = 5
```

What is the best practice/location for doing that.

*Note to others having issues setting this option:* The Google::Apis class does not exist until 0.9.x versions of the google_api_client gem which are not compatible with prior releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the option depends on application instance running, say you need 1 retry on local machine or staging, but want to have 5 retries on production, preferable way to handle this is to keep it in environment variable and fetch it on application startup.

So place following code in your initializer(say `./config/initializers/google_api_client.rb`):

```
Google::Apis::RequestOptions.default.retries = ENV['google_api_client_retries']
```

then you can start application specifying it with:

```
google_api_client_retries=1 bundle exec rails s
```

You can keep environment variables in file(to keep things simple in development environment) using [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), just place it in `./.env` file:

```
google_api_client_retries: 1
```

and it will be fetched automatically, so you start app with just

```
bundle exec rails s
```

---

If you want to just have it 5 on any application instance, you can just explicitly set it to 5 in initializer.